# How can I get input from multiple spinners so I can display results from a database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, spinner

I have 1 activity with 3 spinners, each about a dozen or so options in them.

I would like to get the data from the spinners, access a Sqlite database, then display something in a second activity.

I have the two activities and my database has over 10,000 entries. So before I start building it I want to make sure that I can get the two activities to link properly with the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding SQLite connections: it depends. The sipliest way is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956196/android-how-to-pass-database-adapter-to-another-activity/5956301#5956301).